# Service Locator Pattern in C#: freaky code?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I decided to use a Service Locator pattern in my prj. However I suspect that the current code is freaky. The thing is: I have 3 types but the 3rd one uses the first 2, so it seems to me that the code is not ok, how could I improve it?

Here's the code:

```
public class ServiceLocator: IServiceLocator
{
    private static ServiceLocator _instance;

    private IDictionary<object, object> services;

    private ServiceLocator()
    {
        services = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        this.services.Add(typeof(IService1), new Service1());
        this.services.Add(typeof(IService2), new Service2());
        this.services.Add(typeof(IService3), new Service3(new Service1(), new Service2(), new Service4()));
    }

    public static ServiceLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ServiceLocator();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return (T)services[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Service Locator is most often called an *anti*-pattern, because all classes need a direct dependency on the locator. You don't need it if you use Dependency Injection. Frameworks like ASP.NET MVC and Web API actually depend on DI vs Service Locator.

Comment: Additionally, your singleton implementation isn't thread-safe - see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: In any case, don't try to build your own when there are so many DI libraries out there, except as a learning exercise. For example, the way you register everything in the constructor *hard-codes* the dependencies.  The `Dictionary` class isn't thread-safe and it should be `Dictionary<Type,x>` anyway. You create *all* instances in your constructor, even if you never need them. That can be very expensive. That's why most DI libraries use lambdas to create instances as needed.  And you don't release them at all, leading to resource leaks or blocking as all threads have to access the same service

Comment: comments above are correct. but if you're just create a code for an example to show, what you want, than main mistake of SL pattern usage is that you pass direct dependencies. instead, you could get Service1 and Service2 from your SL to keep using your DI method.